# How to load gif image into webview in background?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in which I am loading gif image from assets. I have 10 fragments in viewpager and each fragment has webview on its top show gif. I am loading gif into webview with  loadDataWithBaseUrl method. But its freezes the scrolling. I need to load gif image into webview in background.

Comment: Try loading via JavaScript within page, rather than having it hardcoded as image source.

Comment: Are you only using WebView so that you can show gif images? Asking because there might be better options available.

Comment: yes i am only using webview .Which is better solution than webview?

Answer (score 0):

check your image size and try loading gif with less than 30kb.One thing you should know that you cant load UI in background thread. if you still have issue in loading gif. try designing html page

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('static.gif')">

</body>
</html>
```